# how to import javascript inside javascript

Tags: javascript, import

so, in HTML, there is the `<script>` tag which allows an importation of javascript to the webpage but is there a way to do something like this is javascript, without using jquery, by abling to import by a js' file's location.

I am aiming to import js to the document by a js file that would be accessed by basic syntax something like 
`importscriptfrom(*filelocationgoeshere*)`

Comment: Your question is not clear.Do you want to add javascript in html?

Comment: yes, where else would it go?